# how to trigger mouseover event only for an img element using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want my mouseover event to only trigger when I hover over an img element only. I used

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img').onmouseover=function(e){ }
```

but it doesn't works. How should i achieve this?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` return `Array like` of elements, so you need to loop through in that array, or use index to target one of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should apply event listeners to elements one by one:

```js
const imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

const map = fn => x => Array.prototype.map.call(x, fn);

map(img => {
  img.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
    e.target.style.border = '1px solid red';
  });
  img.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => {
    e.target.style.border = 'none';
  });
})(imgs)
```

```html
<img src="" width="100" height="100">
<img src="" width="100" height="100">
<img src="" width="100" height="100">
```

Here we extract `map` function from the `Array.prototype` so we can map a function over any iterable object, not just arrays.

The same code with regular ES5 syntax:

```js
const imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

const map = function(fn) {
  return function(x) {
    Array.prototype.map.call(x, fn);
  }
}

const sponge = 'http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/spongebob/images/6/6f/SpongeBob_%286%29.png/revision/latest?cb=20140824163929';

map(function(img) {
  img.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    e.target.src = sponge;
  });
  img.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
    e.target.src = '';
  });
})(imgs)
```

```html
<img src="" width="90" height="80">
<img src="" width="90" height="80">
<img src="" width="90" height="80">
```

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)  of elements. You need to set the event on all elements and not on the Collection.

You can do that like :

```
var arrElem = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var i = arrElem.length; i-- ;) {
  arrElem[i].onmouseover = function(e) {};
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it by 10 seconds. removing my answer.

Comment: 'getElementsByTagName' return not Array, but array like Collection. This Collection will not have array methods: map, forEach ....

Comment: @SergeyOrlov but you can still apply `map` and other `Array.prototype` methods as shown in my answer.

Comment: @wostex Yes you approach is nice.

Comment: Maybe nice but without any explanation. And arrow function is not working on all browsers [source](http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions)

Answer (score 0):

GetElementsByTagName return the Collection of elements. If the is only one `img` it will be the collection with one element. So you need to access property of this collection through `[0]`.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].onmouseover=function(e){ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Would any of these do what you want? You would need [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) for it, but I'd recommend it anyway.

```
$('#img')
    .mousemove(function (event) {
        console.log('Mouse moved');
    })
    .mouseenter(function () {
        console.log('Mouse over');
    })
```

Comment: No jquery tagged.