# How to get img src value on hover, edit and return it on the fly using pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a code for a "Thumbnail Zoom Browser Extension" and I want to capture the `img src` value from websites on mouseover, edit and return it on the fly. With the help of answer to this [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43806433/6171671), So far, I've written code to capture it but I'm struggling to return the value so I can edit it.

**Example Scenario**

```
<img src="pic/th_rose.jpg"  >
<img src="pic/th_tulip.jpg" >

<h1 id="demo">_ _ _ _ _</h1>

<script>
const imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
const map = fn => x => Array.prototype.map.call(x, fn);

// function x(z){ return z; }; /* Doesn't work */
// function x(z){ alert(z); }; /* Does Work    */

map(img => {
    img.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
      // imgs[e.target].onmouseover = x(e.target.src); /* function x(z) */
      // document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x(e.target.src); /* Works Fine */
         var x = e.target.src;
         return x;
      });
})(imgs)
/* I want to display the value here ( outside the function ) as below */
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (imgs); /* returns [object HTMLCollection] */
</script>
```

I've commented out some codes which I was experimenting.

**My question:**

Why does `alert` work,  but not `return`? How can I achieve it? Should I use `JSON`?

**What I'm trying to do is**

1. capture the img src value `pic/th_rose.jpg`
2. remove the `th_`
3. return `pic/rose.jpg`
   It should happen on mouseover to any image.

   **PS:** Please note there are no h1 tag with id='demo' in real scenario, This is an example scenario. I know how to display on id='demo' and that's not what I'm trying to achieve. I want to capture the value on the fly, edit and return it.

Comment: `return x;` Where are you returning ?

Comment: It's for the `Imagus Extention Sieve`, Returning it will get the value and attach it to the link. I've to regEx the image link to create the appropriate full URL.

Comment: That return seem odd, why don't you just do the manipulations inside the handler

Comment: The image hosting site I am trying is a little trickier. it's like this.. `<a href="https://www.imagehosting.com/gallery/flowers/pages/index.html"><img src="images/th_rose.jpg"> Now the link to image should be `https://www.imagehosting.com/gallery/flowers/images/rose.jpg` So, I've to write a regEx to neglect `pages/index.html` from `<a href=` and capture the img src value return it so it will attach it make a valid url. I've to trim `th_` as it's for thumbnail.

Comment: rather than returning it, whenever the mouseover happens you change the href of the `a` which you do inside the even handler.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there are couple of things you are getting wrong here

1. Variable `imgs` is the list of `img` elements as a `DOM Array`. You are not modifying the variable `imgs` so it will stay same.
2. (Considering you are not using events here) If your `fn` takes an input and returns a value,  your map method will return an array of values in the same order of array. That means the method `img => { /* Some function */ }` should return a value, which is not happening here.
3. An event listener is not executed immediately, it will be executed when the event `hover` happens, so you are not gonna get the value of src immediately (or synchronously), so you can't access it immediately after the map method
4. Returning from an event listener is not same as returning from a regular method, you can refer to event handlers [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to understand that.

So, if you want the `src` on `hover`, you can never return it synchronously. You will have to use `callback`. If you want a list of all src values (irrespective of hover), you can get them synchronously.

**Scenario 1:**

```
const imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
const callback = src => {
    console.log(src);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += src;
};

Array.prototype.forEach.call(imgs, img => {
    img.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
        callback(e.target.src.replace('th_', ''));
    });
});
/* I want to display the value here ( outside the function ) as below */
/* You wont be able to do this here, as you don't have values. The hover didn't happen, by the time this code is executed */
```

In this approach, the callback function is called whenever someone hovers on an image, so you can write code to handle the src there.

**Scenario 2:**

Getting the `src` values as an `array` synchronously, but this won't have anything to do with `hover`

```
const imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
const map = fn => x => Array.prototype.map.call(x, fn);
const imageSrcs = map(img => img.src)(imgs);

/* I want to display the value here ( outside the function ) as below */
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = imageSrcs;
```

> PS: Purpose of answers is not to give you working code, but to
>   explain you how things work. You are supposed to rewrite your code on your own, based on the information gained from answers.

Comment: It works on the extension and shows correctly on the console. But is there any way to return the value instead of console.log() ? it's for Imagus Hover Zoom Extension filter.

Comment: As I have told you, if you want src values synchronously you need to use Scenario 2 in which case you cant use hover. If you want them on hover, you need to use callback as shown in Scenario 1 in which case you wont be able to return them.

Comment: If you want to get into Promises you can return a promise which will be resolved when all the img elements have been hovered atleast once

Comment: Will you be able to give me some suggestion or any workaround if I show you the actual work?

Comment: Yes, if you can give the actual scenario and explain clearly what you are trying to achieve, I might be able to help you better

Comment: I've to regEx a part from `<a href=` link and capture and trim `th_` from img src and return it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170489/discussion-between-jeeva-raam-and-avcs).

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer:**

```
<a href="#"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503844281047-cf42eade5ca5?w=200" alt="Kitten"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1496123932780-8a477309b886?w=200" alt="Kitten"></a>

<script type="text/javascript>
function cleanFilename(filename) {
  const newFilename = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1521923898449-d3f0e8fe1845?w=200';
  return newFilename;
}

const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');

images.forEach(image => {
  image.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
    e.target.parentNode.href = cleanFilename(e.target.src);
  });
})
</script>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RyLzWx

If you :hover an image, the parent link will get a new href, that is a modified img src.

**Previous answer:**

This is a small rewrite of your approach:

```
<p>...</p>

<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503844281047-cf42eade5ca5?w=500" alt="Kitten">

<script type="text/javascript">
function cleanFilename(filename) {
  const cleaned = 'CLEANED: ' + filename;
  return cleaned;
}

const paragraph = document.querySelector('p');
const image = document.querySelector('img');

image.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
  paragraph.innerHTML = cleanFilename(e.target.src);
});
</script>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NMaVzz

You can edit the return value in the cleanFilename function.

Comment: It only gets one image src, if you create another img tag with different src and mouseover it, then it doesn't get its src value. It should change the value on moue over the image, If you hover to another image it's src value should appear.

Comment: Do you want to change the image src with a new value, or do you want to display the modified src string somewhere else?

Comment: Its for `Imagus Hover Zoom Browser Extension` filter. I am trying to write a filter for a certain hosting site and it's a little bit trickier. it's like this.. `<a href="https://www.imagehosting.com/gallery/flowers/pages/index.html"><img src="images/th_rose.jpg">` Now the link to image should be `imagehosting.com/gallery/flowers/images/rose.jpg` So, I've to write a regEx to neglect pages/index.html from `<a href=` and capture & return img src value so it will attach it making a valid url. I've to trim th_ as it's for thumbnail. There are diff fields on the filter to capture using regEx or JS.

Comment: Will you be able to give me some suggestion or any workaround if I show you the actual work?